# VBA Compiling problems

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

I'm trying restructure my VBA for sending & Receiving data from Ms access to an Rs 232 Comm Port with the VBA below,but I'm get an error when compiling on the receiving part before iterating the Json Data, kindly see where I'm going wrong:

The first part for sending appear to be okay which is in section A , the problem is section B.

Addition information:

Section A format the raw data into Json and the formatted Json data is sent to the Rs 232 Comm port with Value = 2

Section B this is supposed to read and write received data in Json format into the table by iterating through looping , that is where the problem is. Kindly see how you can help.

**VBA Code to Checked**

```
Private Sub CmdConertJson_Click()
'  Const SQL_SELECT As String = "SELECT * FROM QryJson;"
  On Error GoTo Err_Handler
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim fld As DAO.Field
  Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
  Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
  Dim root As Dictionary
    Set root = New Dictionary

    Dim transaction As Dictionary
    Dim transactions As Collection
    Dim item As Dictionary
    Dim items As Collection
    Dim invoice As Dictionary
    Dim invoices As Collection
    Dim Tax As Collection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Set transactions = New Collection
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("QryJson")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm = Eval(prm.Name)
Next prm
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)

Set qdf = Nothing
 rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Set transaction = New Dictionary
        transaction.Add "PosVendor", "Nector Prime Accounting Solutions"
        transaction.Add "PosSerialNumber", Me.CboEfds.Column(1)
        transaction.Add "IssueTime", Me.txtjsonDate
        transaction.Add "TransactionTyp", Me.TransactionType
        transaction.Add "PaymentMode", Me.PaymentMode
        transaction.Add "SaleType", Me.SalesType
        transaction.Add "LocalPurchaseOrder", Me.LocalPurchaseOrder
        transaction.Add "Cashier", Me.Cashier
        transaction.Add "BuyerTPIN", Me.BuyerTPIN
        transaction.Add "BuyerName", Me.BuyerName
        transaction.Add "BuyerTaxAccountName", Me.BuyerTaxAccountName
        transaction.Add "BuyerAddress", Me.BuyerAddress
        transaction.Add "BuyerTel", Me.BuyerTel
        transaction.Add "OriginalInvoiceCode", Me.OrignalInvoiceCode
        transaction.Add "OriginalInvoiceNumber", Me.OrignalInvoiceNumber

        '--- loop over all the items
        Dim itemCount As Long
        itemCount = Me.txtsquence
        Set items = New Collection
        For i = 1 To itemCount
            Set item = New Dictionary
            item.Add "ItemID", i
            item.Add "Description", DLookup("ProductName", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            item.Add "BarCode", DLookup("ProductID", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            item.Add "Quantity", DLookup("Quantity", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            item.Add "UnitPrice", DLookup("unitPrice", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            item.Add "Discount", DLookup("Discount", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            '--- loop over all the taxes
            Dim taxCount As Long
            taxCount = 1
            Set Tax = New Collection
            Dim strTaxes As Boolean
            strTaxes = DLookup("CGControl", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            '--- loop over all the invoices
            Dim invoiceCount As Long
            invoiceCount = 1
            Set invoices = New Collection
            For j = 1 To invoiceCount

                For t = 1 To taxCount
            Next t
            item.Add "Taxable", Tax

            Tax.Add DLookup("TaxClassA", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            Tax.Add DLookup("TaxClassB", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))

                item.Add "Total", DLookup("TotalAmount", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
                item.Add "IsTaxInclusive", strTaxes
                item.Add "RRP", DLookup("RRP", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))

            Next j


            items.Add item
        Next i
        transaction.Add "Items", items

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    root.Add "", transaction

    Dim JSON As String
    Dim intPortID As Integer ' Ex. 1, 2, 3, 4 for COM1 - COM4
    Dim lngStatus As Long
    Dim strError  As String
    Dim strData   As String
    Dim lngSize As Long
    intPortID = 2
    ' Initialize Communications
    lngStatus = CommOpen(intPortID, "COM" & CStr(intPortID), _
        "baud=115200 parity=N data=8 stop=1")

    If lngStatus <> 0 Then
    ' Handle error.
        lngStatus = CommGetError(strError)
    MsgBox "COM Error: " & strError
    End If


    ' Set modem control lines.
    lngStatus = CommSetLine(intPortID, LINE_RTS, True)
    lngStatus = CommSetLine(intPortID, LINE_DTR, True)

    ' Write data to serial port.
    strData = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(transaction, Whitespace:=3)
    lngSize = Len(strData)
    lngStatus = CommWrite(intPortID, strData)
    If lngStatus <> lngSize Then
    ' Handle error.
    End If

Exit_CmdConertJson_Click:
Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
Resume Exit_CmdConertJson_Click

'Section B
 ' Read maximum of 64 bytes from serial port.
    lngStatus = CommRead(intPortID, strData, 14400)
    If lngStatus > 0 Then
        ' Process data.

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblEfdReceipts")
  For Each item In strData
    rs.AddNew
            rs![TPIN] = item("TPIN")
            rs![TaxpayerName] = item("TaxpayerName")
            rs![Address] = item("Address")
            rs![ESDTime] = item("ESDTime")
            rs![TerminalID] = item("TerminalID")
            rs![InvoiceCode] = item("InvoiceCode")
            rs![InvoiceNumber] = item("InvoiceCode")
            rs![FiscalCode] = item("FiscalCode")
            rs![TalkTime] = item("TalkTime")
            rs![Operator] = item("Operator")
            rs![Taxlabel] = item("TaxItems")("TaxLabel")
            rs![CategoryName] = item("TaxItems")("CategoryName")
            rs![Rate] = item("TaxItems")("Rate")
            rs![TaxAmount] = item("TaxItems")("TaxAmount")
            rs![VerificationUrl] = item("TaxItems")("VerificationUrl")
            rs![INVID] = Me.InvoiceID
            rs.Update
  Next item

  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing

    ElseIf lngStatus < 0 Then
        ' Handle error.
    End If

    ' Reset modem control lines.
    lngStatus = CommSetLine(intPortID, LINE_RTS, False)
    lngStatus = CommSetLine(intPortID, LINE_DTR, False)

    ' Close communications.
    Call CommClose(intPortID)
End Sub
```

[image]

**THE PROBLEM HERE IS HOW DO I PUT THE RECEIVED JSON DATA INTO AN OBJECT SO THAT I CAN ITERATE IT AND UPDATE ITS DATA INTO THE TABLE CALLED tblEfdReceipts**

I have followed your comments kindly check if this is what you meant when you said I need to put into an object:

**REVISED VBA CODE**

```
Private Sub CmdConertJson_Click()
  On Error GoTo Err_Handler
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim fld As DAO.Field
  Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
  Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
  Dim root As Dictionary
    Set root = New Dictionary

    Dim transaction As Dictionary
    Dim transactions As Collection
    Dim item As Dictionary
    Dim items As Collection
    Dim invoice As Dictionary
    Dim invoices As Collection
    Dim Tax As Collection
    Dim Z As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Set transactions = New Collection
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("QryJson")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm = Eval(prm.Name)
Next prm
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)

Set qdf = Nothing
 rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Set transaction = New Dictionary
        transaction.Add "PosVendor", "Nector Prime Accounting Solutions"
        transaction.Add "PosSerialNumber", Me.CboEfds.Column(1)
        transaction.Add "IssueTime", Me.txtjsonDate
        transaction.Add "TransactionTyp", Me.TransactionType
        transaction.Add "PaymentMode", Me.PaymentMode
        transaction.Add "SaleType", Me.SalesType
        transaction.Add "LocalPurchaseOrder", Me.LocalPurchaseOrder
        transaction.Add "Cashier", Me.Cashier
        transaction.Add "BuyerTPIN", Me.BuyerTPIN
        transaction.Add "BuyerName", Me.BuyerName
        transaction.Add "BuyerTaxAccountName", Me.BuyerTaxAccountName
        transaction.Add "BuyerAddress", Me.BuyerAddress
        transaction.Add "BuyerTel", Me.BuyerTel
        transaction.Add "OriginalInvoiceCode", Me.OrignalInvoiceCode
        transaction.Add "OriginalInvoiceNumber", Me.OrignalInvoiceNumber

        '--- loop over all the items
        Dim itemCount As Long
        itemCount = Me.txtsquence
        Set items = New Collection
        For i = 1 To itemCount
            Set item = New Dictionary
            item.Add "ItemID", i
            item.Add "Description", DLookup("ProductName", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            item.Add "BarCode", DLookup("ProductID", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            item.Add "Quantity", DLookup("Quantity", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            item.Add "UnitPrice", DLookup("unitPrice", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            item.Add "Discount", DLookup("Discount", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            '--- loop over all the taxes
            Dim taxCount As Long
            taxCount = 1
            Set Tax = New Collection
            Dim strTaxes As Boolean
            strTaxes = DLookup("CGControl", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            '--- loop over all the invoices
            Dim invoiceCount As Long
            invoiceCount = 1
            Set invoices = New Collection
            For j = 1 To invoiceCount

                For t = 1 To taxCount
            Next t
            item.Add "Taxable", Tax

            Tax.Add DLookup("TaxClassA", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
            Tax.Add DLookup("TaxClassB", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))

                item.Add "Total", DLookup("TotalAmount", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
                item.Add "IsTaxInclusive", strTaxes
                item.Add "RRP", DLookup("RRP", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))

            Next j


            items.Add item
        Next i
        transaction.Add "Items", items

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    root.Add "", transaction

    Dim json As String
    Dim intPortID As Integer ' Ex. 1, 2, 3, 4 for COM1 - COM4
    Dim lngStatus As Long
    Dim strError  As String
    Dim strData   As String
    Dim lngSize As Long
    intPortID = 2
    ' Initialize Communications
    lngStatus = CommOpen(intPortID, "COM" & CStr(intPortID), _
        "baud=115200 parity=N data=8 stop=1")

    If lngStatus <> 0 Then
    ' Handle error.
        lngStatus = CommGetError(strError)
    MsgBox "COM Error: " & strError
    End If


    ' Set modem control lines.
    lngStatus = CommSetLine(intPortID, LINE_RTS, True)
    lngStatus = CommSetLine(intPortID, LINE_DTR, True)

    ' Write data to serial port.
    strData = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(transaction, Whitespace:=3)
    lngSize = Len(strData)
    lngStatus = CommWrite(intPortID, strData)
    If lngStatus <> lngSize Then
    ' Handle error.
    End If
Exit_CmdConertJson_Click:
Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
Resume Exit_CmdConertJson_Click

' Read maximum of 64 bytes from serial port.

Dim JSONS As Object

    lngStatus = CommRead(intPortID, strData, 14400)

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblEfdReceipts")
    If lngStatus > 0 Then
    ElseIf lngStatus < 0 Then
        ' Handle error.
        On Error Resume Next
    End If
        ' Process data.
  Set JSONS = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strData)
    Z = 2
  For Each item In JSONS
           With rs

            .AddNew
            rs![TPIN] = item("TPIN")
            rs![TaxpayerName] = item("TaxpayerName")
            rs![Address] = item("Address")
            rs![ESDTime] = item("ESDTime")
            rs![TerminalID] = item("TerminalID")
            rs![InvoiceCode] = item("InvoiceCode")
            rs![InvoiceNumber] = item("InvoiceCode")
            rs![FiscalCode] = item("FiscalCode")
            rs![TalkTime] = item("TalkTime")
            rs![Operator] = item("Operator")
            rs![Taxlabel] = item("TaxItems")("TaxLabel")
            rs![CategoryName] = item("TaxItems")("CategoryName")
            rs![Rate] = item("TaxItems")("Rate")
            rs![TaxAmount] = item("TaxItems")("TaxAmount")
            rs![VerificationUrl] = item("TaxItems")("VerificationUrl")
            rs![INVID] = Me.InvoiceID
            rs.Update
        End With
        Z = Z + 1
    Next

      rs.Close
      Set rs = Nothing
      Set db = Nothing
      Set JSONS = Nothing

    ' Reset modem control lines.
    lngStatus = CommSetLine(intPortID, LINE_RTS, False)
    lngStatus = CommSetLine(intPortID, LINE_DTR, False)

    ' Close communications.
    Call CommClose(intPortID)

End Sub
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Somehow you must replace `strData` with an object holding your long list of item values.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Even if it contains JSON encoded data, `strData` is still a string, and you can't use `For Each` on it.

Comment: Very clear message. Put data in an array or collection or dictionary object and loop through object elements.

Comment: This where I have a problem , how do I put the received data from rs 232 comm port into that object . The data will be received in (lngStatus = CommRead(intPortID, strData, 14400)) . How do I then create an object to iterate whatever is received from the gadget???????

Comment: What does this string look like? Is there a character that delimits the data elements in the string? Are there multiple records in this string? Possibly parse string to array with Split() function. You should edit question with more info. You should also put error message as text in question.

Comment: And does revised code work? Of what use is looping a recordset if you don't do anything with its data? You might answer questions already asked.

Comment: There was an incomplete link here , even though at the moment I do not have a machine to test it I believe by putting this Set JSONS = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strData) , I should be able to loop through the data received from machine . If you have seen something strange kindly ,tell me exactly where the problem is

Comment: Are there any more issues with the revised code??????????